# Calling Function from another JS file(not a game state) Phaser js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phaser-framework, es6-class

```
import Timer from '../components/Timer.js';

export default class MainGame extends Phaser.State {
    preload() {
        console.log("create");
    }
    create() {
        this.timerJS = new Timer(this.game);
    }
    update() {

    }
}
```

The above code is my MainGame state code. In create I have created Timer.js object. Now, how to call foo() which is written in Timer.js file.
Timer.js is not a state, but just a simple js file.

Comment: Can you show the `Timer.js` file?

Comment: export default class Timer extends Phaser.Game {
 create() {
  console.log("timer",this);
 }

 foo() {
  console.log("new");
 }
}

Comment: Did you try `this.timerJS.foo()`?

Comment: It worked. Thanks. :)

Comment: Added as an answer too for future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If instantiating a new variable reference of a class, you can simply call methods on the class from the variable you create.

So in this case, to call method `foo()`, simply:

```
this.timerJS.foo()
```